# How to print file path and line number while program execution?

Tags: python, debugging

I am running a Python program and I am getting an error. The program is written by someone.

The program has a lot of classes, methods, loops etc.,

Assume that I got an error, the error reporting in Python contains the line number and the nested call information and ends with key error.

I want something like this:

*While the program executes, the output, which I can see in terminal, should contain the filename (or path of the file) and the line number it is executing* and the error reporting should be as usual.

Example (output):

> *file1 line1*: normal output (if any)
>
> *file1 line2*: normal output (if any)
>
> *file2 line1*: normal output (if any)
>
> *file2 line2*: normal output (if any)
>
> *file1 line9*: normal output (if any)
>
> *file1 line10*: normal output (if any)
>
> .......................................

Comment: Are you giving output through `print()` calls or are you using the `logging` module? Because getting line no and file name is pretty easy when using `logging` (You can even achieve this with trivial changes in the source). But it's not so with `print` or `sys.stdout.write` calls.

Comment: @Jalaj I want to do it with `logging` only, not with `print`. But do not know what and where to add.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set up a log format of your choice that consists of `lineno` and `pathname`. Consider this file called `test.py`:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(pathname)s line%(lineno)s: %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO
)
logging.info("test message")
```

And when you run this program,

```
$ python3 test.py
test.py line6: test message
```

Just paste the above snippet in any of your files. Make sure it is executed *before* any calls to any `logging` calls.

Here's a list of all parameters you can use in logging formats: [`logging.LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord)

Answer (score 1):

Use two internal modules of Python (`linecache`, `sys`) :

```
import linecache
import sys

def PrintException():
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    f = exc_info.tb_frame
    lineno = exc_info.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print ('{}, {} "{}" (Error: {})'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj))

try:
    print (1/0) # place here code which you need check
except:
    PrintException()
```